# pass variable in <a href> link

Tags: javascript, arcgis, infowindow

I've searched for this issue, but can't quite find samples that are identical to this. I've tried using single and double quotes in various locations but can't get it to work or get errors.

I just want the variable myLink to display the link in my popup window. Thanks!

```
else {
  var myLink = "http://www.myorg.org/local.html?state=14&local=" + feature.attributes.CITY_NAME;
  var CityCountyTemplate = new InfoTemplate("",
    "City: ${CITY_NAME} <br/> County: ${COUNTY} <br/> State: ${STATE_NAME} <br/> <strong>Link: </strong><a href=myLink> Results page</a>");
  CityCountyTemplate.setTitle("Result");
  feature.setInfoTemplate(CityCountyTemplate);
}
```

Comment: `<a href="+myLink+">` -- basic string concatenation.

Comment: Ahh thanks! I don't know why I thought the second + was not needed unless there was a string after.

Comment: Is there a way I can add target="_new" after the link? I get an unexpected identifier error <a href="+myLink+" target="_new"> Results page</a>");

Comment: Because you're putting double quotes within a double-quoted string. Either switch your outer quotes to single-quote, or escape them with a backspace. `" <-- starts string  ends string-->"+someVariable+"<-- starts string next quote ends string--> target="_new"` -- so do `target=\"_new\"`. You can also just use single quotes for the property; I personally don't like doing that.